# Difference finitely many and arbitrarily many

Tags: elementary-set-theory, terminology, definition

Is there a difference between "finitely many" and "arbitrarily many"? Some notes I am reading are making a point of distinguishing between the two and I thought they meant the same thing.

Comment: maybe they say "arbitrarily many" as for some arbitrary cardinality that is probably bounded by the set you work in, or not, in a proper class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Arbitrarily many" can be infinite where "finitely many" cannot.  A specific example is in topology, where the intersection of finitely many open sets is still open, while the union of arbitrarily many open sets is open.  An example to show the infinite intersection of open sets may not be open comes from $\Bbb R$ with the usual topology.  All the sets of the form $(-\frac 1n,\frac 1n)$ are open for $n \in \Bbb N$, and the intersection of finitely many of them is open, but the infinite intersection is $\{0\}$, which is not open.

Comment: That was exactly the example... how bizarre. Thanks, I thought arbitrary had to be finite for some reason.

Comment: In set theory, arbitrarily many can include cardinal much larger than $\mathfrak c$.  It is "as many as you have".  The example is a classic, certainly not my invention.